# Getting "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" while parsing with Retrofit and GSON

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

After looking for answers for almost a day, I still can't see what's the problem with how I am doing an API call with Retrofit and GSON.

My JSON is this:

```
{"nombre_completo":"placeholder name","edad":"78","email":"2","genero":"1","nombre_pais":"Chile","img_perfil":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com\/imagenes\/1\/perfil\/perfilRecortada.jpg","grados":["FIGHT: 10\u00b0Dan","ANOTHER:Negro 3rd"]}
```

Using a JSONSCHEMA2POGO or SGSON plugin POJO class

```
private String nombre_completo;
private String edad;
private String email;
private String genero;
private String nombre_pais;
private String img_perfil;
private List<String> grados = null;
```

With my GSON and Retrofit implementations as

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();
sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_API)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

And using a async call from Retrofit, I still get the error.

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: Is it grado or grados?

Comment: It's "grados". I must have mistyped while asking. I will correct it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is related to the format of the data you're testing with.  It appears that gson is expecting an array of objects, but you're just giving it a single object.  Try wrapping your test data in square brackets.  More info on this error is at: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/966